# Adding TextField to part through Orchard Migration

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I've created a small banner widget that contains an imagefield and a textfield (for the link target). The ImageField part renders perfectly in the admin view, however the textfield never renders...

Am I doing something wrong?

```
public int UpdateFrom5()
{
    ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("PartnerBannerLong", part => part
        .WithField("Image", field => field
            .OfType("ImageField")
            .WithSetting("ImageFieldSettings.Width", "728")
            .WithSetting("ImageFieldSettings.Height", "90")
            .WithSetting("ImageFieldSettings.ResizeAction", "Validate")
        )
        .WithField("LinkTarget", field => field
            .OfType("TextField")
            .WithDisplayName("Link Target")
        )
    );

    return 6;
}
```

Comment: When you say admin view you mean in the editor? Is the field there when you go to Content / Content Types and then edit the type?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy yes, I mean in the editor. However, this is no longer an issue for me. I wiped the db and moved all of the UpdateFroms into the Create() in the migration. I think the problem was I had the flow of the migration update methods out of order. The text field now properly displays in the editor.

Comment: Yes, chances are, you had updated a migration step that had already run instead of adding a new one? It's easy to miss that step, and once the migration has run, it won't run again.